# How to update in one query in waterline

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

In SQL, I can update a field with inline calculation like this-

```
UPDATE user SET count=count+1 WHERE id=userID
```

It requires only one database operation.

But, in waterline, my only option now is to query the user, change the value, and save back into the database.

```
User.findOne(userID).exec(function(err, user) {
    if(user) {
        user.count++;
        user.save(function(err) {
             if(!err) console.log("success");
        });
    }
});
```

It requires double database access. How can I reduce the overhead?

Comment: It's the only way, but I think it's not a big deal. You can find more than one entry and save more than one user at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute native querys with waterline so I would go that route.

`User.query("query string here", function (err,result){//Handle errors and result here});`

http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/query

Comment: but it actually kills the purpose of waterline. what if I want to change the database system?

Comment: Waterline will never be able to keep up with all forms of query executions that can be made and due to its adapter nature to connect to various databases, which are at various levels of maturity you will always run into these problems. Infact waterline including sails state on their website to not shy away from .query as native calls may be better suited https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/queries/query-methods.md check the .query comments at this link.

Comment: I get it now, thank you. I guess native query is the only option for my case.